# Send Data-Driven SSRS Subscription on Query Data

Tags: reporting-services, subscription, data-driven

I would like to send data-driven subscription on specific date. Query for report:

```
SELECT   PPstart,  PPend,  PmtDate, 
         PayForMonth,      DateAdd(dd, - 3, PPend)      AS SendRpt,
         'Name1@domain.com'                             AS MailTo, 
         Concat(PayForMonth, ' Monthly Payroll Report') AS Subject
FROM     PayPeriodTable
WHERE    YEAR(GETDATE()) = LEFT(PmtDate, 4)
AND      PayForMonth = CONVERT(char(3), GETDATE(), 0)
```

Gives me:

```
PPstart     PPend       PmtDate     PayForMonth   SendRpt     MailTo            Subject
2021-10-18  2021-10-31  2021-11-05  Oct           2021-10-28  Name1@domain.com  Oct Monthly Payroll Report
```

Query is dataset for the subscription, and I would like it to run on SendRpt value every month. Possible without getting into exe files on report server? I do not have access to those.

Comment: Can't you just add a `AND DateAdd(dd, - 3, PPend) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)` to the WHERE clause of your data driven query?

Comment: I have added dd,-3 but sometimes it’s -4, e.g., next months needs to run on thanksgiving Wednesday.  DB table has all pay period end dates and calculated send report date. I am hoping there’s a way to say “send this report when SendRpt=GetDate()